# Can a static final field be initialized in subclasses? If so, how?

Tags: java, static, final

I need to write some code which is as follows:

```
public class Person {
    public static final String NAME;

    public Person(String NAME) {
        this.NAME = NAME;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Player extends Person {
    public Peter(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

It's basically, I want the Player class to have a static final field called NAME, that is being initialized somewhere else, without manually writing in every class `public static final String NAME = "Peter"`.

Is it possible?

Comment: *"why can't i just write "need help with" in the title?"* Because it's a vague, poor title indicative of a potentially vague, poor question. Please come up with a title that actually describes your question. As it is now, your title is not useful.

Comment: You can't change final field value somewhere else without reflection.

Comment: What do you mean, *without manually writing in every class "public static final String NAME = "Peter"*? You just said you want this field just in the Player class, so you'd only have to write that code once.

Comment: Your design doesn't seem to make sense in the real world. A static field is shared between all instances. Do all your people share their name (have the same name)?

Comment: Why do you have to write `public static final String NAME = "Peter"; ` in every class? You can just have the field in one class and use it in others.

Comment: Ok, that was written pretty quickly. I'm going to try to explain it: I want the static field to be initialized in the subclasses. However, they have to be initialized in the main class. So, I am asking if i can initialize them in the subclass.

Comment: But *why* is that field a `static final`? That's telling the compiler that (`static`) - you want all Persons to have a single `NAME` shared among them, and (`final`) - you want the `NAME` to only be initialized *once* when the class is loaded (one time for all people, not one time for each person).

Comment: @RealSkeptic I could be wrong but I think the OP is wanting some way to enforce that every subclass of `Person` has its own separate public static field, without having to declare it explicitly. I guess that's not so unreasonable as every subclass of `Enum` has to have a static VALUES field, but the answer is that you just can't do that.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I think the OP has a bad design in mind, and should understand the meaning of the modifiers and correct the design, or re-read his study materials, to come to a better design that will allow those fields to be initialized in a natural way.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I completely agree. I'm just trying to get my head around what is being asked.

Answer (score 4):

As it has been said in the comments, you have poorly declared your `NAME` variable. In actuality, you don't want it to be `static` (although you can keep the `final` modifier, if you want). Your code should, instead, be something along the lines of:

```
public class Person {
    public final String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Player extends Person {
    public Player(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Every person should have their own name; you don't want all objects to be sharing one `NAME` field

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if I fully understand your question, but I think you have a few mistakes in your code. Like declare name of person as static variable, because static variables are often used as variables for the entire class, and if you changed the name, would change the name to the entire class, not for one instance. Also final is wrong, because you cannot set final variable.

I would do something like this:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Person: %s", this.getName());
    }
}

public class Player extends Person{

    public Player(String name) {
        super(name);
      }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("Player: %s", this.getName());
    }        
}

public class Match {

    private Player player_one;
    private Player player_two;

    public Match(Player player_one, Player player_two) {
        this.player_one = player_one;
        this.player_two = player_two;
    }

    public Player getPlayer_one() {
        return player_one;
    }

    public void setPlayer_one(Player player_one) {
        this.player_one = player_one;
    }

    public Player getPlayer_two() {
        return player_two;
    }

    public void setPlayer_two(Player player_two) {
        this.player_two = player_two;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Right now are playing %s VS %s",player_one.getName(), player_two.getName());
    }
}

public class PlayerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player peter = new Player("Peter");
        Player anna = new Player("Anna");
        Match tennisMatch = new Match(peter, anna);
        System.out.println(tennisMatch.toString());
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I static field (variable) only exists once for all instances of your class. Therefore what you try does not work by design.

What value would you expect the field to have after you created three different instances of this class using different parameters?

A final variable cannot be changed once it got initialized. For static variables this happens before the first instance of the class is even constructed. At the moment the constructor is executed the field cannot be changed anymore.

To initialize a static final variable you have to assign a value directly at the definition using the = operator or you have to do it in a static initializer which looks like this:

```
public class FooBar {
    public static final String STATIC_VARIABLE;

    static {
        STATIC_VARIABLE = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can make it like this:

```
private static final NAME;

public Player(String name){
    NAME = name;
}
```

A final varible can be initialized once only if it wasn't initialized yet.
So in this way the constructor is helping you make it.